# SSIS - Using different credentials for source and destination

Tags: ssis

My source connection is a warehouse that has its own team providing us with a windows credential. Due to other security constraints on the destination side, we can't grant the same credential write access to the destination.

As a result, both the source and the destination use different windows credentials in the data-flow task. My earlier solution was to make use of the windows credential manager and map the source cred there, and execute the package with the credential used to access my destination.

However, we recently moved to new servers and due to org policy no longer get Remote access to the DB box where the package has been placed and hence can't set credentials via credential manager anymore. We only get access to deploy the package to catalog and run it from there.

Is there an alternate option to use two different sets of windows credentials in the same SSIS package? Deploying to SQL/SSIS 2017.

Comment: Adding Credential Manager as an approach to my bag of tricks. Usually I tell people it's RunAs or a job with the appropriate credentialed entity but mixing them, I don't know how that'd work. My guess is that they're going to force you to redesign packages to have reader packages stage data to files and then writer packages pick that data back up and push it to the target. That's going to slow down total execution as you're reading and writing your data twice over.

Comment: You might need to engage your manager and point out that existing, perfectly working deliverables are being impacted by this other team's decision. They need to provide us a solution for handling the multi-windows user thing as the existing workaround we had doesn't work anymore. They broke it, they gotta find us a solution to make it work again (or unbreak it).

Comment: We are trying to engage the appropriate team to atleast add the credential to the credential manager. Was just wondering if there was a different solution that would work. One option I tried is to add a new credential using cmdkey via execute process task, but the task just failed so am guessing that's due to a rights issue on the account running the job to the DB box itself.

Comment: Can one of the credentials be SQL authentication instead of windows which can be defined in the connection string? The usual process is that they grant your service account access to read data from their system.

Comment: We are actually trying that approach, but that is proving hard as SQL ID creation is prohibited unless an exception is granted. We are going with the proviso that they either grant us RDP access to add credentials to the credential manager or allow us to create SQL account to bypass the issue.